# Receiving badges from poor questions?

Tags: discussion, badges

It seems like some of the badges can be earned through poor questions, which in some ways defeats the merit that the badge is supposed to reflect. For example, the Notable Question requires 2500 views on a single question. The problem is that a question becomes notable if it is really good OR if it is really bad. Would it make sense to put a requirement of at least positive upvotes on certain badges? Or is it truly the intent of the badge to merely reflect views?

Case in point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630713/is-it-true-in-python-that-you-can-import-specific-functions-from-a-module-unlike

Comment: I bet this is so rare that hardly anyone cares...

Comment: *Most* really bad questions get very few views, and most questions that get lots of views are at a minimum, mediocre.  The remaining exceptional cases aren't really worth attempting to handle.

Comment: There are >10k users that I consider to be quite terrible. Outliers happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question you pointed out is kind of special, because it had a lot of points but seems that because of the `OP`'s behavior, it lost a lot making it keep a deeply negative scoring, so I think this is not a good example. I neither think that bad questions receive too much visits, at least I haven't seen a case like that.

Comment: Fair enough, it bothered me just enough to ask ;)