# The Peer Pressure badge seems to invite bad posts, is that so?

Tags: discussion, badges

Now that I'm more aware of sly and underhanded methods to gain reputation (having tried a few), I find myself looking at the [**Peer Pressure badge**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) and thinking:  **How easy.**

Racking up high viewership with a ridiculously bad post [sounds chancy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251246/122139), but *deleting my own mediocre post with score of -3 or lower* -- that's a low-brainer!

This badge seems guaranteed to generate at least one bad-quality post for every member who shares my insight and really wants the bronze.  Those who [acquire it seem to show](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) qualities contrary to those we typically try to cultivate.

<strike>I might even suggest its removal.</strike>

**Can I ask for an explanation on the purpose of this badge?**

Comment: Sure, some users are dumb enough to want the badge for the badge's sake. They run the risk of being closer to a post ban for it. Note that the badge is only awarded when they *remove* the bad post again though, so it is kind of self-cleaning too.

Comment: Related: [Badges should reward positive behavior](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107628)

Comment: Ah, my search didn't pull up that post. It seems to me the community STILL has to endure that bad post from the "dumb enough".

Comment: @mehow, that was an enlightened edit (your strike-through). (I presume it's yours.) Changes tone of post.  Changes people's reactions. Thanks.

Comment: @Smandoli thanks -> the power of community edits proved once again -> you can see the [revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/255671/revisions) on your post by clicking the *`edited x time ago`* link next to your signature.

Comment: @Smandoli the change of reaction might have been due to the retag as well.  On Meta site, users often user votes to express agreement/disagreement, and this is especially true of feature requests.  Many might have been just saying "No do not remove this".  But changing it to a discussion, removes that aspect and leaves it as a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Excepting Jon Skeet, *everybody* will write a bad post sooner or later. At that point the badge is a itty-bitty, little compensation for the embarrassment.

Comment: Pity though, now I’m good at writing posts, I can’t really earn this, and I don’t want to lose >= 6 rep. And get flagged.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As mentioned in [Michael Mrozek's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/145982/michael-mrozek) answer to the related question on MSE, [Badges should reward positive behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107628/badges-should-reward-positive-behavior), badges always meet one of 2 criteria:

1. Encourage positive behavior.
2. Compensation.

I would also add as 3rd criteria that badges also exist to educate users about features of the site, which is somewhat part of the encouraging positive behavior.

The Peer Pressure badge exists solely for Encouragement and Education.  We like it when someone learns the ability to recognize that their post does not meet the site's criteria and deletes it themselves.  This is positive behavior because it saves the community and the moderators the effort of having to delete it themselves.  There is also an educational aspect because not everyone is familiar with how deletion works, or that you will recover your lost rep when you delete your downvoted post.

There are always going to be users who intentionally post a bad question just to get the badge.  However, that can easily backfire because if someone posts an answer that gets upvoted, then the user will be unable to delete it and won't recover the rep and won't get the badge.  Of course this won't stop anyone who wants to post a bad answer and delete it when it gets 3 downvotes (unless it gets accepted, which would be extremely unlikely).  But in the end, it's a self-cleaning issue as the user will get his/her badge, and the post will be deleted.

Answer (score 11):

I'll make a point for not necessarily bad posts, but killing content a bit. I have mostly lurked on StackOverflow thus far as I got a feel for the community.

I asked a bad question earlier today and deleted it when I got a handful of negative votes. Those votes served as a smack on the wrist, then I saw my rep going down, more wrist smacking, and then I got a sort of "You gave in to peer pressure" badge that seemed to mock me. Three different "You screwed up, mate" reactions seemed a bit over the top. I still need the info I was asking for, but instead of meticulously trying to edit my content to be SO friendly so I don't get the triple-smackdown, I'm just going to ask it on a friendlier forum. I really did legitimately try to get it right the first time. So content moves away from SO a bit. I got my rep back later, but at the time I didn't know I was going to, and I was quite upset to have lost my handful of points I got from taking an hour to type out an answer.

I get the point of the badge though, but maybe a different name, as peer pressure has always had extremely negative connotations tied to drugs/booze/bad decisions. Maybe changing the name to something like **Better Luck Next Time**-- or a little extra info like "You'll get your rep back."

Reddit Thread with currently 188 upvotes on the peer pressure badge making people feel stupid: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/2zp22c/how_im_sure_most_firstposters_on_stackoverflow/cplcg9i

Comment: I like most of your points, but saying 3 people out of the hundreds of thousands of voting users saying they didn't like your post is a "smackdown", seems a bit harsh. Note that besides deleting, votes can be *reversed* after an edit if the voter likes the new version.

Comment: I had -3 within less than a minute. By itself I don't think that would have been too bad. It's the combination of 3 things-- downvotes, rep loss(I'm new, didn't know I'd get that back), and a badge that seems...sarcastic for lack of a better word... **all at once** seemed like overkill. Also, while I know votes can be reversed I feel like many people wouldn't go back and bother to do so.  Since this is a badge aimed at newbies to encourage good behavior, I think a bit of tweaking to it would make it more "I'll post better" than "I won't post at all now."

Comment: Also I wanted to say I think that's why Smandoli took it as humor-- because it kind of pokes at the user, hopefully somewhat in jest because this is otherwise a pleasant site to interact with.

Comment: No problem changing the badge if people are taking it wrong :)

Comment: Though that would be a [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: Took your advice, Deduplicator. I made it a feature request. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284854/peer-pressure-badge-needs-tact-tweak-it

Comment: Separate thread was deleted as a duplicate of this one.